# Java simple counting words in a file

Tags: java

I am creating a simple program that counts the number of words, lines and total characters (not including whitespace) in a paper. It is a very simple program. My file compiles but when I run it I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:838)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1347)
    at WordCount.wordCounter(WordCount.java:30)
    at WordCount.main(WordCount.java:16)
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.io.*;
 public class WordCount {
//throws the exception
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    //calls on each counter method and prints each one
    System.out.println("Number of Words: " + wordCounter());
    System.out.println("Number of Lines: " + lineCounter());
    System.out.println("Number of Characters: " + charCounter());

}

//static method that counts words in the text file  
public static int wordCounter() throws FileNotFoundException { 
//inputs the text file
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("words.txt")); 
    int countWords = 0;
    //while there are more lines
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        //goes to each next word
        String word = input.next();
        //counts each word
        countWords++;
    }
    return countWords;
}

//static method that counts lines in the text file  
public static int lineCounter() throws FileNotFoundException {
//inputs the text file
Scanner input2 = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"));
    int countLines = 0;
    //while there are more lines
    while (input2.hasNextLine()) {
        //casts each line as a string
        String line = input2.nextLine();
        //counts each line
        countLines++;
    }
    return countLines;
   }    

//static method that counts characters in the text file 
public static int charCounter() throws FileNotFoundException {
//inputs the text file
Scanner input3 = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"));
    int countChar = 0;
    int character = 0;
    //while there are more lines
    while(input3.hasNextLine()) {
       //casts each line as a string
        String line = input3.nextLine();
        //goes through each character of the line
        for(int i=0; i < line.length(); i++){
            character = line.charAt(i);
             //if character is not a space (gets rid of whitespace)
            if (character != 32){
                //counts each character
                countChar++;
            }
        }           
    }
   return countChar;
}
}
```

Comment: Whats in words.txt file?

Comment: Just asked a few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13729294/422353

Comment: try using inputStreamReader [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) instead of Scanner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really say the exact reason for the problem without looking at the file (Maybe even not then).

```
   while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        //goes to each next word
        String word = input.next();
        //counts each word
        countWords++;
    }
```

Is your problem. If you are using the `input.hasNextLine()` in the while conditional statement use `input.nextLine()`. Since you are using `input.next()` you should use `input.hasNext()` in the while loops conditional statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int wordCounter() throws FileNotFoundException 
{ 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("words.txt")); 
    int countWords = 0;

    while (input.hasNextLine()) {

        if(input.hasNext()) {
            String word = input.next();
            countWords++;
        }
    }

    return countWords;
}
```

I have just added an `if` condition within the while loop. Just make sure to check there are token to be parsed. I have changed only in this place. Just make sure to change wherever needed.

This [link](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/02/how-to-solve-javautilnosuchelementexcep.html) will give good info. in regard to that.

Hope it was helpful. :)