# java - Scanner class NoSuchElementFoundException

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, java-io

I am trying a program in Java. My code goes as follows

```
class Main{
    static Employee getData() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(
                            new DataInputStream(System.in)
                            ));
        System.out.printf("Enter Employee ID : ");
        int tmpid = Integer.parseInt(rdr.readLine());
        System.out.printf("Enter Employee Name : ");
        String tmpname = rdr.readLine();
        System.out.printf("Enter Employee Salary : ");
        int tmpsalary = Integer.parseInt(rdr.readLine());
        rdr.close();
        return new Employee(tmpid, tmpname, tmpsalary);
    }   
    public static void main(String []args){
        boolean b = false;  
        String path = null;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        File file = null;
        try {
            System.out.printf("Enter path to save your file : ");
            path = s.next();
            file = new File(path);
            if (!(file.createNewFile()))
                System.out.println("Error creating file");
        } catch (Exception ie) {
            System.err.println("Exception : " + ie);
        }       


        do{
            try {
                Employee rec = Main.getData();
                ObjectOutputStream dos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
                dos.writeObject(rec);
                dos.close();
                System.out.printf("Add more records [true/false]? ");
                s = new Scanner(System.in);
                    int tmp = s.nextInt();
            } catch (Exception ioe) {
                System.err.println("Exception : " + ioe);
            }

        }while(b);
    }
}
```

When I run this program I get NoSuchElementFoundException when second time `s.nextInt()` is executed. I tried out every possible methods but with no result. What is the problem over here?

Comment: You are asking `Add more records [true/false]?` So for that what are you entering as response?

Comment: Please refer to the comment that @Adaam has posted in his own question. Here I find there is nothing to do with environmental issues in my case.

Comment: Sorry for `Add more record [true/false]?` that is the part of the program that I actually want to code but taking `s.nextBoolean()` too failed so I tried with `s.nextInt()`

Comment: @StillALearner Which line is causing the exception ?

Comment: `int tmp = s.nextInt()`

Comment: Post the stacktrace fully.

Comment: `Enter path to save your file : /home/kernel-love/4.txt
Enter Employee ID : 1
Enter Employee Name : abc
Enter Employee Salary : 456
Add more records [true/false]? java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextBoolean(Scanner.java:1825)
 at Main.main(StreamCollection.java:65)`

Comment: It seems the Scanner is not able get the feed from user. That's why it is throwing error.

Comment: To the person who added the comment that this was answered some other place, they are wrong. His problem (this question) was about closing the resource that is backing the Scanner. The problem you are linking to is about asking for an int (scanInt) when there is not an int there. Same error message but they get there two different ways to get that error message, related but not duplicated.. Please unmark or clarify the link to the other. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729294/nosuchelementexception-with-java-util-scanner

Comment: Those who have marked my question duplicate must refer to the link they have suggested. That person has some environmental issues with his program and his code does not contain any exception. My question is genuine and is different from what that person's problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never catch an exception unless you are going to do something useful with it.

I got it to work. It was fairly straight forward.

```
Enter path to save your file : myfile.bin
Enter Employee ID : 99
Enter Employee Name : Rick Hightower
Enter Employee Salary : 99
Add more records [true/false]? true
Enter Employee ID : 77
Enter Employee Name : Dippy Do
Enter Employee Salary : 88
Add more records [true/false]? false
```

Here is what I have:
...

```
public static class Employee implements  Serializable {

    int id;
    String name;
    int salary;

    public Employee(int id, String name, int salary) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

}

static Employee getData() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
                    new DataInputStream(System.in)
            ));
    System.out.printf("Enter Employee ID : ");
    int tmpid = Integer.parseInt(rdr.readLine());
    System.out.printf("Enter Employee Name : ");
    String tmpname = rdr.readLine();
    System.out.printf("Enter Employee Salary : ");
    int tmpsalary = Integer.parseInt(rdr.readLine());
    //rdr.close(); this is why... you broke it :)
    return new Employee(tmpid, tmpname, tmpsalary);
}

public static void main(String []args) throws Exception {
    boolean moreRecords = true;
    String path = null;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    File file = null;
    System.out.printf("Enter path to save your file : ");
    path = scanner.next();
    file = new File(path);


    while (moreRecords) {
        Employee rec = Main.getData();
        ObjectOutputStream dos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        dos.writeObject(rec);
        dos.close();
        System.out.printf("Add more records [true/false]? ");
        moreRecords = scanner.nextBoolean();
    }
```

It is mostly your code with some parts taken away.

The biggest issue you had was you were closing the input stream.

```
static Employee getData() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
                    new DataInputStream(System.in)
            ));
    System.out.printf("Enter Employee ID : ");
    int tmpid = Integer.parseInt(rdr.readLine());
    System.out.printf("Enter Employee Name : ");
    String tmpname = rdr.readLine();
    System.out.printf("Enter Employee Salary : ");
    int tmpsalary = Integer.parseInt(rdr.readLine());
    //rdr.close(); this is why... you broke it :)       <-------------------SEE
    return new Employee(tmpid, tmpname, tmpsalary);
}
```

The Java I/O stream uses the decorator pattern so it just keeps delegating the close call into the inner streams.

That fixes that problem. There are lots of problems with your code.

If you are using JDK 1.7 or later, it will close the file for you.

```
    while (moreRecords) {
        Employee rec = Main.getData();

        try ( ObjectOutputStream dos =
                     new ObjectOutputStream(
                             new FileOutputStream(file) ) ) {

            dos.writeObject(rec);

        }

        System.out.printf("Add more records [true/false]? ");
        moreRecords = scanner.nextBoolean();
    }
```

If you are using JDK 1.6 or JDK 1.5:

```
    while (moreRecords) {
        Employee rec = Main.getData();

        ObjectOutputStream dos = null;
        try {
            dos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                            new FileOutputStream(file) );
            dos.writeObject(rec);

        } finally {
           if ( dos!=null  ) {
                dos.close();
           }
        }

        System.out.printf("Add more records [true/false]? ");
        moreRecords = scanner.nextBoolean();
    }
```

Also, your program should do more validation of user input. Scanner can do that as follows:

```
public static class Employee implements  Serializable {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal salary;

    public Employee(int id, String name, BigDecimal salary) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

}

static Employee getData(Scanner scanner) throws IOException {

    System.out.printf("Enter Employee ID : ");
    while ( !scanner.hasNextInt() ) {
        System.out.println("Employee IDs are numbers only");
        scanner.next();
    }

    int employeeId = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.printf("Enter Employee Name : ");
    String name = scanner.next();


    System.out.printf("Enter Employee Salary : ");

    while ( !scanner.hasNextBigDecimal() ) {
        System.out.println("Employee salaries are decimals " +
                "not random gak");
        scanner.next();
    }
    BigDecimal salary = scanner.nextBigDecimal();

    return new Employee(employeeId, name, salary);
}


public static void main(String []args) throws Exception {
    boolean moreRecords = true;
    String path = null;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    File file = null;
    System.out.printf("Enter path to save your file : ");
    path = scanner.next();
    file = new File(path);


    while (moreRecords) {
        Employee rec = Main.getData(scanner);

        try ( ObjectOutputStream dos =
                      new ObjectOutputStream(
                            new FileOutputStream(file) ) ) {
            dos.writeObject(rec);

        }

        System.out.printf("Add more records [true/false]? ");
        moreRecords = scanner.nextBoolean();
```

Now the input/output is more like this:

```
Enter path to save your file : asdfasdf
Enter Employee ID : 9a
Employee IDs are numbers only
99
Enter Employee Name : Rick
Enter Employee Salary : aa
Employee salaries are decimals not random gak
99.99
Add more records [true/false]? false
```

The scanner forces the end user to enter in the right types of data.
You can combine it with regex to match patterns for names, etc.

I extended the example and added some discussion of the Scanner.

http://rick-hightower.blogspot.com/2013/10/java-scanner-example.html

Comment: I didn't get the code you have written for the Java 7 version. Whats that new feature in try block introduced in Java 7?

Comment: There is no finally block. You put the "closeable" (Closable interface) in the try parents `try ( ObjectOutputStream dos =
                     ... ) {` Then you don't need a finally block. I am new to it as well. I often use the finally block. You have to do one or the other if you are dealing with files since FILE_DESCRIPTORS are a limited resource (10K to 300K and no more and it depends on the  OS settings).

Answer (score 1):

In [nextInt(),](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) `NoSuchElementFoundException` occurs when the input is exhausted. So check the input that you give at prompt.

Comment: I input an integer number I am sure about that.