# "Java.Util.NoSuchElementException: No Line Found"

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

//I am not able to figure out what is wrong? Please help me. I was able to use the //scanner .I am not able to input the values.Java.Util.NoSuchElementException: No Line //Found.

```
 //String arrayValue = null;
                    int Rows= boardsize, Columns=boardsize;
                    int[][] sudokuArray = new int[Rows][Columns];
                    String[] sudokuTempArray;
                    String delimiter = "\\,";

                    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
                    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);


                    for(int i=0;i<Rows;i++ ){   
                        System.out.println("Enter the value of array separated by ',' for row" + i);

                        while(userInput.hasNext())
                        {
                            String arrayValue = userInput.next();
                            sudokuTempArray = arrayValue.split(delimiter);
                            if(sudokuTempArray.length == Rows)
                            {

                                for (int j = 0;j<Columns;j++)
                                {
                                    sudokuArray[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(sudokuTempArray[j]);
                                    System.out.println(sudokuArray[i][j]);
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        /*
                            else
                            {
                                System.out.println("Try again!");
                            }*/


                    }
```

Comment: Which is line number cause exception? tell the line number or post the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

If you have used a scanner previously reading from System.in and have closed that scanner, you will have closed the System.in InputStream.

Have you previously closed a scanner reading from System.in?

Comment: yes. if(userInput.hasNextInt()) {
   boardsize = userInput.nextInt();
   //userInput.close(); I am still not able to add all the values in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a common error. Look at my answer to this question.

[java - Scanner class NoSuchElementFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463627/java-scanner-class-nosuchelementfoundexception/19463980#19463980)

He essentially closed the input in another method, which you are likely doing as well.

Search for .close in your code base.

See this:

[java - Scanner class NoSuchElementFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463627/java-scanner-class-nosuchelementfoundexception/19463980#19463980)

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
class shift
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    void test(int x)
    {

```
    String s=sc.nextLine();
    StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(s);
    String wen="";
    {
        while(st.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            String temp=st.nextToken();
            for(int i=1;i<=x;i++)
            {
                wen=wen+temp+" ";
            }
        }
        System.out.print(wen);
    }
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=sc.nextInt();
    shift reff=new shift();
    if(n<=0)
    {
        System.out.print("EMPTY");
    }
    else
    {
    reff.test(n);
    }
}
```

}
//output : java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found