# Java simple calculator Error

Tags: java, calculator

I am very new to java and i'm trying to make a basic calculator. There is another question on this but I changed the things that fixed it for him but it still doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;  

class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String args[])

        int num1;
        int num2;
        String op;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your first number");

        num1 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter your second number");
        num2 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the operation");
        op = input.nextLine();

        if (op.equals("*")){
            System.out.println("The answer is: " + (num2 * num1));
        }

        if (op.equals("/")){
            System.out.println("The answer is: " + (num2 / num1));
        }

        if (op.equals("+")){
            System.out.println("The answer is: " + (num2 + num1));
        }

        if (op.equals("-")){
            System.out.println("The answer is: " + (num2 - num1));
        }
     }
  }
```

The error says:

```
Enter your first number
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:12)
```

I can't seem to find whats wrong (I have its something simple that i missed)

Comment: Why do you need the second `Scanner`? Which is line `12`?

Comment: This error is for `main()` method of `HelloWorld` application.

Comment: I don't think i do. I got rid of it but it gives me the same error.

Comment: See if you're **closing** scanner anywhere in your code.

Comment: The code you have posted is **not** the code generating that stack trace.

Comment: I'm pretty shure you would get the wrong results for non-commutative operations (i.e. -, /) even if you solve the error, since you exchanged the operands. (You want to input A before B for calculating A / B , right?)

Comment: As an aside, after you figure out what's causing the exception, you might want to give http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextxxx a read, *especially* if you end up with a program that is "not reading in the inputted operation".

Comment: possible duplicate of [NoSuchElementException with Java.Util.Scanner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729294/nosuchelementexception-with-java-util-scanner)

Answer (score 2):

What are you entering?

```
Enter your first number
10
Enter your second number
20
Enter the operation
*
The answer is: 200
```

Comment: I doesn't allow me to enter anything. It gives the Error right away.

Comment: @user3126413 How are you invoking it?

Comment: what do you mean by invoking it?

Comment: How are you running (or starting) your program?

Comment: at the moment im just using an online compiler (I'm not at my home computer) usually I use Eclipse

Comment: @user3126413 Apparently your online compiler doesn't have a console. Sorry.

Comment: When I test the code, it terminates after it says `Enter the operation`

Comment: @mikeyaworski How are you running it? I just launched it in eclipse... it worked fine.

Comment: Eclipse. I have no idea why, but when I ran `op = input.next();` instead of `op = input.nextLine();`, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure your program would even compile the way you have it, but here's one problem:

You didn't open your `main` method with an open curly brace.

Change this:

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

to this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
```

---

When I tested your code, it terminated after `Enter the operation`. However, when I changed this line:

```
op = input.nextLine();
```

to this:

```
op = input.next();
```

It worked perfectly.

Here is an example of the console input/output:

```
Enter your first number
10
Enter your second number
20
Enter the operation
*
The answer is: 200
```

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I see wrong is `public **satic** void main(String args[])`  Other than that it's doing what it should...

Comment: okay yeah that was me typing it in (I accidentally deleted that after coping the code in)

Comment: The OP says that they're getting at least the first line to print out to the console. If this `satic`/`static` thing were the problem, the program wouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever, you read any token from Scanner. You have the facility to check whether it really exists with hasNext() methods. So, you can do

*For checking ints :*

```
if(input.hasNextInt())
input.nextInt()
```

*For checking lines :*

```
if(input.hasNextLine())
input.nextLine()
```

This will get rid of the `NoSuchElementException`

Update:

```
 System.out.println("Enter the operation");
 op = input.next(); //changing it to next() fixed it
```

**Output**

```
 run:
    Enter your first number
    2
    Enter your second number
    3
    Enter the operation
    *
    The answer is: 6
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)
```

Comment: Not in this case. `Ststem.in` stream always has `next`.

Comment: You mean System.in? Can you please explain a bit?

Comment: `hasNext()` will always return `true` when reading from `System.in`, since there is no such thing as the end of file for keyboard input.  Obviously, the same is not true for `hasNextInt()` or any other type-specific method.

Comment: Thanks for the point on *System.in*. if the same is not true for hasNextInt() method, then when can we use it?