# Java - Reading first word of text file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am having trouble reading the first word of a text file. If the first word equals 'Circle' I want to create a new Circle object in my array.

```
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("shapeFile.txt");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(fileIn);
            while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
                String shape = scan.next();
                if(shape.equals("Circle")) {
                  myShapes.addShape(new Circle(scan.nextInt(), scan.nextInt(), scan.nextInt(), Color.RED));
                }
            }
```

I am getting the following error for the above code, pointing to the line String shape = scan.next();

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
    at shapes.ShapeManagement.main(ShapeManagement.java:151)
Java Result: 1
```

If anyone could help me resolve this I would be most grateful.

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc if s/he didn't, it would be a compile-time error, not runtime.

Is line 151 `String shape = scan.next();`?

Comment: Can you add a sample of the input file please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NoSuchElementException with Java.Util.Scanner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729294/nosuchelementexception-with-java-util-scanner)

Comment: @pennstatephil Good point.  Time to get some coffee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to modify the code as follows:

```
 FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("shapeFile.txt");
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(fileIn);
 int[] var1 = new int[3];

 while(scan.hasNext()) {
     String shape = scan.next();
     if(shape.equals("Circle")) {
       for(int i = 0; i < 3;i++) {
          if(scan.hasNextInt()) {
            var1[i] = scan.nextInt();
          } else {
            break;
          }
       } 

       myShapes.addShape(new Circle(var1[0], var1[1], var1[2], Color.RED));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason your likely getting this exception is because `scan.hasNextLine()` can return `true` even if there are no tokens on that line. If you call `scan.next()` when there are no tokens after the marker, you will get the `java.util.NoSuchElementException` you are seeing.

So, swap out `scan.hasNextLine()` for `scan.hasNext()`.

Alternatively you could swap out `scan.next()` for `scan.nextLine()` and then check whether the first word in that line was the one you are looking for. This could potentially be faster for files with large numbers of lines.

I hope this helps.

[Link to the Scanner API for reference.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)