# NoSuchElementException Do not Solve

Tags: java

I am new to Java.Doing Practice on it from Java the complete reference.
Now an exception occurred i have done all suggestion which is in this link 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729294/nosuchelementexception-with-java-util-scanner#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729294/nosuchelementexception-with-java-util-scanner#_=_)

But Still I gets the error. I am using Eclipse IDE

Code is here.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculater {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner IO=new Scanner(System.in);
        char input;
        System.out.println("Please Enter \n '+' for Addition  \n'-' for Subtraction \n '*' for Multiplication \n '/' for Division = ");
        input=IO.next().charAt(0);
        if(input=='+' || input=='-' || input=='*' || input=='/') {
            IO.close();
        } else {
            System.out.println("You entered Wrong operater!!!!!!!!");
            Calculater.main(args);
        }
        if(input == '+') {
            Calculater cal=new Calculater();
            cal.addition();
        }
    }

    public  void addition(){
        Scanner IO= new Scanner(System.in);
        double num1,num2,num3;
        char choice;
        System.out.println("Please Enter 1st Number = ");
        if(IO.hasNextDouble()) {
            num1=IO.nextDouble();
        } else {
            num1=0;
        }
        System.out.println("Please Enter 2nd Number =  ");
        if(IO.hasNextDouble()) {
            num2=IO.nextDouble();
        } else {
            num2=0;
        }
        num3=num1+num2;
        System.out.println("After Addtion Answer is = "+num3);
        System.out.println("Do You Want more Calculation Enter 'Y' for Yes and any key for No = ");
        choice=IO.next().charAt(0);
        IO.close();
        if (choice == 'Y') {
            String[] args = {};
            main(args);
        } else {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

OutPut Is This

```
   Please Enter 
   '+' for Addition  
   '-' for Subtraction 
   '*' for Multiplication 
   '/' for Division = 
                +
    Please Enter 1st Number = 
    Please Enter 2nd Number =  
    After Addtion Answer is = 0.0
    Do You Want more Calculation Enter 'Y' for Yes and any key for No = 
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at Calculater.addition(Calculater.java:87)
at Calculater.main(Calculater.java:37)
```

Comment: Please post your exception stack trace and explain what input you provided at the console to get the error.

Comment: Please format your code. Please use Java naming conventions - variables should be in `camelCase` - `PascalCase` is reserved for classes.

Comment: `at Calculater.addition(Calculater.java:87)` - what is line 87?

Comment: I did not entered any Input Everything happen on its own

Comment: choice=IO.next().charAt(0);     Boris the Spider

Comment: The problem seems to be closing the `Scanner` and then trying to read on it. Just remove those naive `IO.close` calls and close it until the very end of your program.

Comment: Thanks Done Luiggi Mendoza

Answer (score 5):

(Moved from comment)

The problem seems to be closing the `Scanner` and then trying to read on it. Just remove those naive `IO.close` calls and close it until the very end of your program.

Answer (score 2):

From what i can gather is it is trying to read the numbers for addition/subtraction before the have been entered and it doesn't wait for anymore input before continuing the application.

For instance you are closing the input stream with the `.close();`method before it can read anything else, so try removing those lines of code until the application has reached its end.

Output of application:

```
Please Enter 
 '+' for Addition
+
Please Enter 1st Number = 
Please Enter 2nd Number =  
After Addtion Answer is = 0.0
Do You Want more Calculation Enter 'Y' for Yes and any key for No = 
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
    at zip.Calculater.addition(Calculater.java:85)
    at zip.Calculater.main(Calculater.java:40)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

try a different approach using `IO.next();`witch will wait for input before moving to the next line of code.

i would suggest something like this:

```
package zip;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculater
{
    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter \'+\' for addition.");

        if(!console.next().equals("+"))
        {
            System.out.println(console.next() + "is not an accepted character.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Enter first number followed enter then the second number followed by enter.");
            String f = console.next();
            String s = console.next();

            int fI = Integer.parseInt(f);
            int sI = Integer.parseInt(s);

            System.out.println(fI + " + " + sI + "=" + (fI + sI));
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter '+' for addition.
+
Enter first number followed enter then the second number followed by enter.
56
23
56 + 23=79
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 7 seconds)
```

also try not to use capital letters for object names, use a capital letter at the start for a class name and a small letter at the start for an object name.