# Error Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java

I wrote is very simple calculator in Java, but I've got a problem in this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Operation extends Declaration {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int w = 0;
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=0;i<1;){
            System.out.println("WYBIERZ RODZAJ DZIALANIA: ");
            System.out.println("1- DODAWANIE");
            System.out.println("2- ODEJMOWANIE");
            System.out.println("3- MNOZENIE");
            System.out.println("4- DZIELENIE");
            input=scan.next();
            if(validate(input)){
                m = Integer.parseInt(input);
                if(m > 0 && m < 5){
                    i++;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Podaj liczbe w zakresie 1-4. ");
                }
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Niestety, podana wartosc nie jest liczba calkowita. ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I'm getting an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at Operation.main(Operation.java:15)
    at Calculator.main(Calculator.java:5)
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you please add an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  and the data for input?

Comment: @Jens what for? The error message says all we need to know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NoSuchElementException with Java.Util.Scanner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729294/nosuchelementexception-with-java-util-scanner)

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    ..
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
```

If we read the [documentation of the Exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html), it states (bold emphasis of mine):

> **Thrown by the nextElement method** of an Enumeration to indicate that there are **no more elements** in the enumeration.

If we assume that input has been declared correctly, the error is still in this line:

```
input=scan.next();
```

There is no next element. Call hasNext() before, to make sure that there actually is a next element.

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared the variable input in your code.
and for taking string `input` write something like this,

```
String input=scan.nextLine();
```

for taking integer as an input write:

```
int input=scan.nextInt();
```

where scan is your Scanner object

Comment: that's not the problem here.

Comment: You edited your answer and yet it is still false. Read the documentation for `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: Ok i got it ,but input is still not declared, ... :( @Theolodis

Comment: In the code snippet, yeah. But neither is `validate(input)`. But that's not leading to the error the OP is having. If you feel unsure about a Question don't answer it and request clarification from the OP in the comments.

Comment: @Theolodis I was going to point validate too,anyways thanks... :) I will take care of this :)

Answer (score 0):

The line 15 in the Operation class is: `input=scan.next();`
The documentation page for that method, assuming that the variable was declared (you would have had a compilation error otherwise) is: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29.

NoSuchElementException is thrown when there are no more available tokens. You have to call `hasNext()` to correct your program.