# java.util.NoSuchElementException on scanner

Tags: java

I have a scanner called input with this code:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int cFreq = 0;

    System.out
            .println("Enter the symbol which you want to find the frequency of:");
    char s = 'a';
    symbolLoop: while (s == 'a') {
        try {
            s = input.next(".").toLowerCase().charAt(0);
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid symbol!");
            input.next();
        }
        switch (checkSymbol(s)) {
        case 0:
            s = 'a';
            break;
        case 1:
            break symbolLoop;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
        cFreq += words.get(i).find(s, true);
    }
    System.out.println("Number of times " + s + " is in the coded words: "
            + cFreq);
}
```

However when it reaches the line where it reads from the scanner it terminates with this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1418)
at Home.frequency(Home.java:118)
at Menu.select(Menu.java:58)
at Menu.view(Menu.java:17)
at Home.main(Home.java:22)
```

(Home is the name of the class).
I have no idea what is causing this and would appreciate some help! :)
Thanks!
EDIT:
I have also tried with this code: `String str = input.nextLine();` in the same method but it throws the same error.

Comment: If there is no period in the String returned by your Scanner, you will get a null pointer exception when you try to convert it to lowercase. Why are you looking for a period in the Scanner input?

Comment: It doesn't even get that far though @DaaaahWhoosh

Comment: "When it reaches the line where it reads from the Scanner". I must have misunderstood, what line is the problem, then?

Comment: It prints out "Enter the symbol which you want to find the frequency of:" but then immediately throws the exception before text is entered, with the error being the line "s = input.next(".").toLowerCase().charAt(0);"

Comment: I've just tried using a Scanner to initialise a String and it comes up with the same error

Comment: I'd suggest looking into [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729294/nosuchelementexception-with-java-util-scanner). It seems to be similar. Unless Daniel's answer works for you.

Comment: For sooner and better answers post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), full (compilable) but short code which will let us reproduce your exact error.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh neither work :(

Comment: Did you perhaps close `System.in` (or some other closable instance like Reader/InputStream which used it) somewhere before using `next`?

Comment: @Pshemo I had closed a different scanner in a different class and that was the problem! Thank! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If data from user wouldn't match `"."` regex (possibly surrounded by delimiters - whitespaces) `next(".")` would't throw `NoSuchElementException`, not `InputMismatchException`.

`NoSuchElementException` exception is thrown when Scanner can't even hope for more data, in which case it is sure that potentially next element will not even exist. Such situation is only possible if Scanner knows that source of data will not have more elements, which in case of Stream is when we will read entire content of stream (like in case of FileInputStream) or it will be closed.

In case of `System.in` we can assume that content of this stream is infinite, because it is provided by user, so when we try to read from it, application is waiting until user will provide its data. Which means that only way Scanner would throw NoSuchElementException is when `System.in` was closed, so `next` doesn't have more data to read.
To avoid such cases you should avoid closing streams which are using `System.in` because you will not be able to reopen it again in your application.