# How can I take an integer as user input from the command line in java?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

This program is meant to use only if statements to take in three numbers as user input, and then print them to the screen in ascending order. However, when I attempt to run this code, I receive the following ouput:

```
Enter first number: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at OrderNumbers.main(OrderNumbers.java:10)
```

This is the code that I am currently running:

```
import java.util.*;

public class OrderNumbers{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("Ordering 3 whole numbers \n");

      System.out.print("Enter first number: ");
      int numberOne = scan.nextInt();
      System.out.print("Enter second number: ");
      int numberTwo = scan.nextInt();
      System.out.print("Enter third number: ");
      int numberThree = scan.nextInt();

      if( numberOne > numberTwo && numberTwo > numberThree){
         System.out.println( "Ordered numbers are: " + numberThree + ", " + numberTwo + ", " + numberOne);
      }
      else if( numberOne > numberTwo && numberThree > numberTwo) {
         System.out.println( "Ordered numbers are: " + numberTwo + ", " + numberThree + ", " + numberOne);
      }
      else if( numberTwo > numberOne && numberOne > numberThree) {
         System.out.println( "Ordered numbers are: " + numberThree + ", " + numberOne + ", " + numberTwo);
      }
      else if( numberTwo > numberOne && numberOne < numberThree) {
         System.out.println( "Ordered numbers are: " + numberOne + ", " + numberThree + ", " + numberTwo);
      }
      else if( numberThree > numberOne && numberOne < numberTwo) {
         System.out.println( "Ordered numbers are: " + numberOne + ", " + numberTwo + ", " + numberThree);
      }
      else if( numberThree > numberOne && numberOne > numberTwo){
         System.out.println( "Ordered numbers are: " + numberTwo + ", " + numberOne + ", " + numberThree);
      }
   }
}
```

I do not know where the error lies, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you running the code, and did you enter any numbers?

Comment: The error is in line 10 of your code, as it says here: at OrderNumbers.main(OrderNumbers.java:10)

Comment: Code is running fine. but there is issue with ordering of the output.

Comment: `Ordering 3 whole numbers 
Enter first number: 5
Enter second number: 4
Enter third number: 6
Ordered numbers are: 4, 6, 5` This is the result i got . What numbers did you give as input ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729294/nosuchelementexception-with-java-util-scanner.  Plus solve your problem with array and sort

Comment: Obviously your if-else conditions are wrong. You want logic for ordering three numbers?

Comment: @Kibadachi `print them to the screen in ascending order` meaning of this to sort the input number in increasing order. I tired `1, 4, 7` and got output as `1, 7, 4` the expected output should be  `1, 4, 7`. Is my understanding correct.

Comment: Code is fine, only problem is with ordering, plz specify what are you giving as input.

Comment: I don't have any exception with your code. However, your logic in "numberTwo > numberOne && numberOne < numberThree" is not really correct. For example: first = 3, seconde = 5, third = 4. It will print: 3,5,4. :) Is that the one you want?! or you would like to print: 3,4,5?!

Answer (score 0):

The exception might be thrown because you're not entering a number. You should check if your input is a number with `input.hasNextInt()` and print error if it's not the case with `input.next()`(which returns a `String` ) to see what you're taking from input.