# Run Time Error: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

Following is the code for a program to calculate the maximum product subarray. But this code gives me the following exception:
Run Time Error

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class GFG {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int noOfCases = s.nextInt();
//  System.out.print("Enter length of array");
    int n = s.nextInt();
    int[] arr = new int[n];
    int i=0;
//  System.out.print("Enter array elements");
    while(i<n){
        arr[i] = s.nextInt();   //error here
        i++;
    }   
    largestProductSubarray(arr);
}

static void largestProductSubarray(int[] arr){
    int n = arr.length;
    int maxUntilNow = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int productTillHere = arr[0];
    for(int i=1; i<n; i++){
        if(productTillHere ==0){
            productTillHere = arr[i];
            continue;
        }
        if(arr[i] < Math.abs(productTillHere * arr[i])){
            productTillHere = productTillHere * arr[i];
        }else{
            productTillHere = arr[i];
        }
        maxUntilNow = Math.max(maxUntilNow, productTillHere);
    }
    System.out.print(maxUntilNow);
}
```

}

Comment: Please add the entire exception (including Stack Trace) to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729294/nosuchelementexception-with-java-util-scanner