# Simple menus using Do-while loops in java

Tags: java, do-while

I am trying to make a simple menu using a do-while loop in java. My code looks like this:

```
int choice;
    Scanner scanChoice = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        System.out.println("Pick an option. 1 2 or 3.");
        System.out.println("1. Apple");
        System.out.println("2. Pear");
        System.out.println("3. Pineapple");

        choice = scanChoice.nextInt();
    } while (choice < 1 || choice > 3);

    System.out.println("You picked " + choice);
```

The problem is, every time I try to run it, it throws "java.util.NoSuchElementException". The full error is below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at mainPackage.Main.fruitMenu(Main.java:135)
at mainPackage.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

I know that this is because `scanChoice.hasNextInt()` returns false, but I'm not sure how to fix this. When I add an if statement (`if (scanChoice.hasNextInt())`), the method `scanChoice.hasNextInt()` still returns false, so it just passes over the line that initializes the variable `choice`, and that variable never gets initialized.

Anyone know how to fix this?

EDIT: The problem is that it does not wait for the user to input another integer. The function `scanchoice.nextInt()`, and the function `scanChoice.nextLine()`, both immediately return no value, without waiting for the user to input a value. Any way to make it wait for input?

Comment: But you did type in a number, not just hit `enter`, right?

Comment: It doesn't give time for me to type a number. It just goes right ahead and throws the `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: How do you run that code? It shouldn't give you that exception unless you start it with an empty standard input, e.g. through a script or maybe within an IDE that doesn't support text input for command line apps. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729294/nosuchelementexception-with-java-util-scanner#comment18864529_13729470

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work for me, consistently. For any valid integers it works as expected, either accepting the input or goes through a loop, and when typing invalid input like "abcd" it throws `InputMismatchException`, that is the expected behavior anyway.

[Online Java compiler IDE](https://www.codiva.io/p/42fbbfdc-831e-4460-99dd-cb7ccb59471b)

Comment: my code does not wait for me to input any value. It immediately returns no value, giving me that exception

Answer (score 0):

I made your code more robust.  It catches alphanumeric characters and displays the menu again, rather than abending with a InputMismatchException.

Here's a test run.

```
Pick an option. 1 2 or 3.
1. Apple
2. Pear
3. Pineapple
x
Pick an option. 1 2 or 3.
1. Apple
2. Pear
3. Pineapple
asdf
Pick an option. 1 2 or 3.
1. Apple
2. Pear
3. Pineapple
2
You picked 2
```

And here's the code.  I called the Scanner nextLine method.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MenuTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int choice;
        Scanner scanChoice = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.println("Pick an option. 1 2 or 3.");
            System.out.println("1. Apple");
            System.out.println("2. Pear");
            System.out.println("3. Pineapple");

            String input = scanChoice.nextLine();
            choice = convertToInteger(input.trim());
        } while (choice < 1 || choice > 3);

        System.out.println("You picked " + choice);
        scanChoice.close();
    }

    private static int convertToInteger(String input) {
        try {
            return Integer.valueOf(input);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I am running this in Eclipse IDE, and the code you put in the `main(String[] args)` function is, in my program, in its own function, which is called in the `main()` function. When I try to run your code, I still get the same error, a `java.util.NoSuchElementException`. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Lucas B: Did you run my code exactly as I wrote it, with no changes?  Because I pasted the test run in the answer.  If you have a different problem, then you need to post **all** of your code in your question.