# What is wrong with my scanner code?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with my code as shown below? The first case works perfectly fine but the second and third case throws an exception :

Does this have something to do with the while loops at the start of case 2 and 3?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int option = scan.nextInt();

    switch (option) {
        case 1: int line = scan.nextInt();
                for (int i = 0; i < line; i++){

                    String operator = scan.next();

                    int n1 = scan.nextInt();
                    int n2 = scan.nextInt();

                    Boolean no1 = (n1 == 1) ? true:false;
                    Boolean no2 = (n2 == 1) ? true:false;

                    if (operator.equals("AND")) {
                        int result = (no1 && no2) ? 1:0;
                        System.out.println(result);
                    } else {
                        int result = (no1 || no2) ? 1:0;
                        System.out.println(result);
                    }

                }
                break;
        case 2: while (!scan.nextLine().equals("0")) {
                    String operator = scan.next();

                    int n1 = scan.nextInt();
                    int n2 = scan.nextInt();

                    Boolean no1 = (n1 == 1) ? true:false;
                    Boolean no2 = (n2 == 1) ? true:false;

                    if (operator.equals("AND")) {
                        int result = (no1 && no2) ? 1:0;
                        System.out.println(result);
                    } else {
                        int result = (no1 || no2) ? 1:0;
                        System.out.println(result);
                    }

                }
                break;
        case 3: while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                    String operator = scan.next();

                    int n1 = scan.nextInt();
                    int n2 = scan.nextInt();

                    Boolean no1 = (n1 == 1) ? true:false;
                    Boolean no2 = (n2 == 1) ? true:false;

                    if (operator.equals("AND")) {
                        int result = (no1 && no2) ? 1:0;
                        System.out.println(result);
                    } else {
                        int result = (no1 || no2) ? 1:0;
                        System.out.println(result);
                    }
                }
                break;
        default: System.out.println("Error");
                 break;
    }
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
>
> at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
>
> at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
>
> at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:64)

Comment: The exception is java.util.NoSuchElementException

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full stack trace of any errors you get.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoSuchElementException with Java.Util.Scanner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729294/nosuchelementexception-with-java-util-scanner)

Answer (score 0):

In case 2:

```
while (scan.nextLine().equals("0"))
```

The above line reads the next line. Then the next time you call `scan.next()` you may not have anything to read. That's why you get  `java.util.NoSuchElementException` exception.

In the while loop, check with `scan.hasNext()`. Then inside the while loop, read the input and check whether it equals to `0`.

```
while (!scan.hasNext()) {
    String operator = scan.next();
    if (operator.equals("0")) break;
    int n1 = scan.nextInt();
    int n2 = scan.nextInt();

    boolean no1 = (n1 == 1) ? true:false;
    boolean no2 = (n2 == 1) ? true:false;

   if (operator.equals("AND")) {
           int result = (no1 && no2) ? 1:0;
           System.out.println(result);
   } else {
           int result = (no1 || no2) ? 1:0;
           System.out.println(result);
   }

}
break;
```

Comment: I tried doing as above and the program runs, but there is no output. To test my program I use the following code : `java HelloWorld < hello.in > output.out` In the file hello.in for case2 contains: 2\nOR 0 1\nAND 0 0\n0

Comment: I didnt call scan.nextLine() cause of this ^ @11thdimension

Comment: There's an error in the code above, it should be while (scan.hasNext()) not !scan.hasNext(). Fixed that and case 2 runs fine :)

Comment: Okay I got all 3 cases to work! Thanks everybody for the help. Much appreciated! @11thdimension

Comment: ahh.. Yes, Fixed it

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner.nextInt()` won't consume the new line followed by it.

That's why `scan.nextLine()` call in the second case would consume `\n`, a single new line character, making the while condition `true`.

Thus inputted `"0"` is still not consumed and would go in `operator`, input meant for the operator would be a string and would not be consumed by scan.nextInt(), this is the error.

To remedy this, call `scan.nextLine()` after the first `scan.nextInt()` call.