# Pascal's Triangle - Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, exception

I really need help within the next 4 hours. I am trying to create a program that takes in an int and outputs a Pascal's Triangle of that size. However, once I tried to take in the value of "ROW" through the Scanner, I have been getting the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at Pascal.main(Pascal.java:9)
```

The program seems fine if I define ROW as a static int along with int "max", but as soon as I use Scanner with it, the problem resurfaces. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pascal {
    private static int max = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int ROW = kb.nextInt();
        int[][] pascal = new int[ROW + 1][];
        pascal[1] = new int[1 + 2];
        pascal[1][1] = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i <= ROW; i++) {
            pascal[i] = new int[i + 2];
            for (int j = 1; j < pascal[i].length - 1; j++) {
                pascal[i][j] = pascal[i - 1][j - 1] + pascal[i - 1][j];
                String str = Integer.toString(pascal[i][j]);
                int len = str.length();
                if (len > max)
                    max = len;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= ROW; i++) {
            for (int k = ROW; k > i; k--)
                System.out.format("%-" + max + "s", " ");
            for (int j = 1; j < pascal[i].length - 1; j++)
                System.out.format("%-" + (max + max) + "s", pascal[i][j]);
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Vote to close as "unclear" since you wouldn't get this exception if you would run your program correctly. And since you don't do that and since you haven't told use ***how*** you run your code, it is therefore unclear not possible to answer properly.

Comment: Sorry, I am a novice at coding. How do I "run my program correctly"? And how should I detail "how" I run my code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729294/nosuchelementexception-with-java-util-scanner

Comment: You can run your code correctly by using any IDE or your console. Incorrectly would be stuff like an online IDE, since they require predifined input values. *"And how should I detail "how" I run my code?"* By telling use *how* you actually run your code.

Comment: I previously used JCreator while executing and received the same error message. However, I am now on a computer that doesn't have JCreator and thus am using an online IDE. Nonetheless, the error message is the same. Does that clear up how I run my code? Sorry again for my ignorance.

Comment: Thanks, @yvs. I tried the change in the thread you commented. After making that change I now get the following error: 
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at Pascal.main(Pascal.java:16)

Comment: Probably its the web IDE, it's buggy, it can't read the user input or bind the javascript event or manage the System.in.

Comment: Ok, thanks Jalal. So you're saying that the code should work fine without errors given that I rerun this code on JCreator again?

Comment: Try running your code on the console instead.

Comment: My teacher requires that the code be run through JCreator. If I continue to see the error message, I can at least rest assured that the code itself is fine, right?

Comment: Then try to find out how to work with `System.in` in `JCreator`, it may require some settings. And yes, your code is fine: http://ideone.com/JsGD44

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution using matrix...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PascalTriangle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Type N: ");
        pascalTriangle(scanner.nextInt());
        scanner.close();
    }

    public static void pascalTriangle(final int N) {
        int[][] triangle = new int[N][N];

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                if (j == 0)
                    triangle[i][0] = 1;
                else
                    triangle[i][j] = triangle[i - 1][j - 1] + triangle[i - 1][j];
                System.out.print(triangle[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Type N: 13
1   
1   1   
1   2   1   
1   3   3   1   
1   4   6   4   1   
1   5   10  10  5   1   
1   6   15  20  15  6   1   
1   7   21  35  35  21  7   1   
1   8   28  56  70  56  28  8   1   
1   9   36  84  126 126 84  36  9   1   
1   10  45  120 210 252 210 120 45  10  1   
1   11  55  165 330 462 462 330 165 55  11  1   
1   12  66  220 495 792 924 792 495 220 66  12  1
```