# Error while scanning for int using Scanner class

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, java.util.scanner

I have an assignment to make which reads as following -
Read 2n numbers as input where the first number represents a key and second one as value. Both the numbers are of type integers.

Write a function getAverageOfOdd to find out average of all values whose keys are represented by odd numbers. Assume the average is an int and never a decimal number. Return the average as output. Include this function in class UserMainCode.

In a Class Main which would be used to read 2n numbers and build the hashmap. Call the static method present in UserMainCode.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class MasteringHashmap

{
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    String number;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=sc.nextInt();

    //get next 2n numbers i.e n key value pairs using getValues() function into a hashmap
    HashMap<Integer,Integer> map = getValues(n);
    int out = UserMainCode.getAverageOfOdd(map);
    System.out.println(out);
    //fill your code here

}
static HashMap<Integer,Integer> getValues(int n)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    HashMap<Integer,Integer> hm = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        int k = sc.nextInt();
        int v = sc.nextInt();
        hm.put(k, v);
    }
    return hm;
  }
}

class UserMainCode {

public static int getAverageOfOdd(HashMap<Integer,Integer>h1)
{

    //fill your code here
    Set<Integer> keys = h1.keySet();
    Iterator<Integer> it = keys.iterator();
    int key,count=0,sum=0;
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        if((key=it.next())%2!=0)
        {
            count++;
            sum+=h1.get(key);
        }
    }
    return sum/count;
    //return 0;
   }
}
```

When I run this code on my laptop it runs fine but somehow the online judge responds with the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
    at MasteringHashmap.main(MasteringHashmap.java:14)
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: this is unrelated to the error but your `map` is null and you're passing it to  a method attempting to invoke methods on it.

Comment: Does the online judge provide any detail about how they run it?  Seems like they are probably feeding the input in a way that your code is not expecting.

Comment: @Aominè I've edited the code, actually the getValues() method is for that purpose only but forgot to add it to the main() function.

Comment: @BPS it just says to Take care of whitespace/trailing whitespace,
Trim the output and avoid special characters,
Avoid printing unnecessary values other than expected/asked output

Comment: This code works fine. The problem can be user input. Use validations on user input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're opening two `Scanner` instances on `System.in` and they're interfering with each other. The first Scanner probably buffers up some of the input, leaving nothing for the second Scanner, causing it to throw an exception.

You should open up a single `Scanner` in `main` and pass it to the `getValues` method:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();

    //get next 2n numbers i.e n key value pairs using getValues() function into a hashmap
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = getValues(n, sc);
    ...
}

static HashMap<Integer, Integer> getValues(int n, Scanner sc) {
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        int k = sc.nextInt();
        int v = sc.nextInt();
        hm.put(k, v);
    }
    return hm;
}
```

Comment: it worked, using double Scanner instances simultaneously was the reason.

Answer (score 0):

NoSuchElementException Thrown by the nextElement method of an Enumeration to indicate that there are no more elements in the enumeration.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html

How about this :

```
if(input.hasNextInt() )
 number1 = input.nextInt(); // if there is another number  
else 
 number1 = 0;
```

This question on SO answers your question. Please refer to it: [NoSuchElementException with Java.Util.Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729294/nosuchelementexception-with-java-util-scanner)