# Search a String and print next 5 lines using PDFBox for PDF files

Tags: apache-poi, java.util.scanner, pdfbox

I don't understand what is wrong in statement while((p=scan.next())!=null). By using scanner object i wanted to print lines after searching a string if(p.startsWith("START")). scanner object throwing a java.util.NoSuchElementException in the main.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.InvalidPasswordException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
public class ReadWriteTest {
static int i;
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws InvalidPasswordException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidPasswordException, IOException {
        POIFSFileSystem fs = null;
        PDDocument pdDoc = null;
        String target_dir = "E:\\TEST_pdfs";
        File dir = new File(target_dir);
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        {
        for ( int s=0;s<files.length;s++){
        if(files[s].isFile()){
        pdDoc = PDDocument.load(files[s]);
        //fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(files[s]));
        PDFTextStripper Stripper =  new PDFTextStripper();
        String st = Stripper.getText(pdDoc);
        String linesp = System.lineSeparator();
        String[] paragraphs = st.split(linesp);
        for(String p: paragraphs){
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(p);
            while((p=scan.next())!=null) {
                if(p.startsWith("START"))
                    do{
                        i++;
                        String nextline = scan.next();
                        System.out.println(nextline); 
                                        }while(i<5);
            }
            }
        }

        }}}}

Error :
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
    at ReadWriteTest.main(ReadWriteTest.java:35)
```

Comment: Unclear what you're asking - do you want some mark that separates paragraphs? Then call pdfStripper.setParagraphStart() and/or pdfStripper.setParagraphEnd() with something.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr i wanted to search a String then after print next 5 lines using scanner object but i dnt know in pdfStripper. i want to use this to parse PDFDoc into paragraphs, String[] like this.

Comment: Seems you didn't understand me and I didn't understand you... Btw, `String name = "value";` is useless, `name` is reassigned the result of `scan.next()` in the next line. Later, `name.startsWith(name)` is always true.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I understood, instead "name" i use foreach String "str" like below. so pls suggest anything like this using pdfStripper "String[] paragraph= we.getParagraphText();"
for ( String str : paragraph){
Scanner scan =  new Scanner(str);
while((str=scan.next()) !=null){
if(str.startsWith(name)){
       do{
     i++;
     String nextline = scan.next();
     System.out.println(nextline);
    }while(i<5);
   }

Comment: Please update the question with that code. Then explain (in the question) what you expect. Maybe link to a pdf, or explain what you expect for the PDF https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12870831/PDFBOX-3804-singlespaced.pdf .  Explain also what you mean with "i wanted to search required lines" and "String[] like this".

Comment: @TilmanHausherr updated.

Comment: Ah, one thing is new: you have trouble extracting tables. You could try `stripper.setSortByPosition(true);` sometimes this helps. Your code has a new problem: `str.startsWith("name")` is not the same as `str.startsWith(name)`. Besides, Scanner finds simple tokens (see javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html ). So you will never get something that starts with "Using great volumes". You'll get "Using", "great", "volumes".

Comment: I don't want to extract tables. I added these two statements String st = Stripper.getText(pdDoc); String linesp = System.lineSeparator(); which can allow PDFbox doc into String[]. Now i wanted to search a string and print next lines. code and error updated.

Comment: Scanner is an iterable. You have to call `hasNext()` before calling `next()`. See also the javadoc of NoSuchElementException https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoSuchElementException with Java.Util.Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729294/nosuchelementexception-with-java-util-scanner)