# what does NoSuchElementException mean and how to solve?

Tags: java, sorting, exception, alphabetical, nosuchelementexception

We were given a .txt file full of names and were asked to put those names in alphabetical order by last name (bonus, if we can also sort by first name). We were tasked to create three different files, Person, SortName, and SortNameApp.

We have to use

```
 Scanner input=new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
```

to look for the file instead of using a BufferedReader.

this is what i have completed of each so far

Person:

```
class Person {
String firstName;
String lastName;
}
```

SortNames:

```
class SortNames {

void sortNames(Person[] arr, int type) {
    if (type == 1) {
       int j;
       boolean flag = true; // will determine when the sort is finished
       Person temp;
       while (flag) {
           flag = false;
           for (j = 0; j < arr.length - 1; j++) {

               if (arr[j].lastName
                       .compareToIgnoreCase(arr[j + 1].lastName) > 0) { // ascending
                                                                           // sort
                   temp = arr[j];
                   arr[j] = arr[j + 1]; // swapping
                   arr[j + 1] = temp;
                   flag = true;
               }
           }
       }
       for (int k = 0; k < arr.length; k++)
           System.out.println(arr[k].firstName +"<-->"+arr[k].lastName);
   } else if (type == 2) {

       int j;
       boolean flag = true; // will determine when the sort is finished
       Person temp;
       while (flag) {
           flag = false;
           for (j = 0; j < arr.length - 1; j++) {

               if (arr[j].firstName
                       .compareToIgnoreCase(arr[j + 1].firstName) > 0) { // ascending
                                                                           // sort
                   temp = arr[j];
                   arr[j] = arr[j + 1]; // swapping
                   arr[j + 1] = temp;
                   flag = true;
               }
           }
       }
       for (int k = 0; k < arr.length; k++)
           System.out.println(arr[k].firstName +"<-->"+arr[k].lastName);
   }
  }

}
```

SortNameApp:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SortNameApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   Scanner reader;

   try {

       Scanner input =new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
       int namesCount = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine().trim());
       Person[] arr = new Person[namesCount];
       String line = null;
       int i = 0;
       while ((line = input.nextLine()) != null) {
           Person person = new Person();
           // System.out.println(line);
           person.firstName = line.split(" ")[0];
           person.lastName = line.substring(person.firstName.length(),
                   line.length()).trim();
           arr[i] = person;
           System.out.println(arr[i].firstName +" "+arr[i].lastName);
           i++;
       }
       System.out.println("---------------------");
       new SortNames().sortNames(arr, 1);// sort by last name
       System.out.println("---------------------");
       new SortNames().sortNames(arr, 2);// sort by first name
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
 }
```

As you can see, the line right here prints out the text file as it already is,

```
System.out.println(arr[i].firstName +" "+arr[i].lastName);
```

But when it comes to applying the sorting algorithm into the code im left with this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found 
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source) 
 at SortNameApp.main(SortNameApp.java:16)
```

My question is what exactly does this mean and whats one possible way to solve it? I'm really sorry if this is a basic knowledge question, but im fresh new to java so all this is foreign to me

Comment: What's the value of `args[0]` (i.e. is it a filename that exists in your application directory)?

Comment: You need to check if `input.hasNextLine()`.

Comment: which line is line 16?

Comment: @ScaryWombat `while...`

Comment: @matt, yes names.txt is in my directory

Comment: I thought as much - see @shmosel comment

Comment: Most of the code and tags aren't relevant to the question btw. Next time try to post a [mcve].

Comment: "What exactly does this mean?" ---  You can handle this part yourself by reading the [`Scanner.nextLine()` docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--):  "Throws: `NoSuchElementException` - if no line was found".

Comment: See also: "[`NoSuchElementException` with `Java.Util.Scanner`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729294/nosuchelementexception-with-java-util-scanner)" and the [`nosuchelementexception` tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/nosuchelementexception/info).

Comment: Your Person class should implement the Comparator interface or you should provide a Comparator implementation.  This will simplify your sort method and you can eliminate the type 2 sort.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use your `Scanner` as if it were a `BufferedReader`, but a `Scanner` isn't just a drop-in replacement for a `BufferedReader`.

Instead of the `BufferedReader`-style code:

```
while (line = input.nextLine()) != null) {
    ...
```

you need to do this instead:

```
while (input.hasNextLine()){
    line = input.nextLine();
    ...
```

Comment: In addition...  I don't think [`Scanner.nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) _can_ return `null`.