# java.util.NoSuchElementException when using Scanner.nextInt()

Tags: java

Total newbie here, Why am i getting an error for using Scanner?
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
class myCode
{
   public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
   {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int s,v1,v2,t1,t2;
    s = sc.nextInt();
    v1=sc.nextInt();
    v2=sc.nextInt();
    t1=sc.nextInt();
    t2=sc.nextInt();
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at myCode.main(file.java:13)
```

Comment: After you started your program, did you type five integers?  Or a mixture of numbers and text?

Comment: program doesn't compile.

Comment: It clearly compiles if you're getting a `NoSuchElementException`, that only occurs at runtime.

Comment: Click the button that says "Show Standard Input", and then enter five integers (separated by white space).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729294/nosuchelementexception-with-java-util-scanner

Comment: Use System.out.println("\n");  whenever you press Enter key it consider it as an input also. That's why all errors are showing.