# java.util.NoSuchElementException at unknown source

Tags: java, exception, nosuchelementexception

I am not sure why I am getting this error. When I run my program I get this

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
```

I am only running one scanner and it's closed after this while loop. I was curious if anyone can give me a hint on how I should five it. Here is some of the code. I also made a comment on line 27 since that is where the error is occurring at i think.

```
        try {
        File file = new File("src/text.txt");
        File finalGrades = new File("src/nextText.txt");
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(finalGrades);
        File finalGradesReport = new File("src/nextTextReport.txt");
        PrintWriter output2 = new PrintWriter(finalGradesReport);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

        double totalPointsAvailable = input.nextDouble();
        double homeworkWeight = input.nextDouble() / totalPointsAvailable;
        double projectsWeight = input.nextDouble() / totalPointsAvailable;
        double firstExamWeight = input.nextDouble() / totalPointsAvailable;
        double secondExamWeight = input.nextDouble() / totalPointsAvailable;
        double finalExamWeight = input.nextDouble() / totalPointsAvailable;

        int numA = 0, numB = 0, numC = 0, numD = 0, numF = 0, numStudents = 0;
        double totalPercGrades = 0, averageGrades = 0;

        while (input.hasNext()) {
            double hw = input.nextDouble() * homeworkWeight;
            double pw = input.nextDouble() * projectsWeight; //line 27
            double firstEx = input.nextDouble() * firstExamWeight;
            double secondEx = input.nextDouble() * secondExamWeight;
            double finalEx = input.nextDouble() * finalExamWeight;
```

Comment: wrap your nextXXX() codes into `  while(input.hasNext()) {....}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.util.NoSuchElementException - Scanner reading user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042008/java-util-nosuchelementexception-scanner-reading-user-input)

Comment: You're getting this error because there aren't enough elements in your file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoSuchElementException with Java.Util.Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729294/nosuchelementexception-with-java-util-scanner)

Answer (score 1):

The error is occurring for two reason.

1. You are not checking if there is enough input before calling on `nextDouble()`.
2. `hasNext()` checks for the next token but is not incremented by calling `nextDouble()`. You want to use  `hasNextDouble()`

You should wrap `nextDouble()` in a while loop and use a counter or just a conditional before each `nextDouble()` to make sure that there is a double token in your file and to keep track of where you are in the file

Something like this should be used:

```
//...below Scanner input = new Scanner(file); 
int tokenCounter = 0;

//This will set all of your variables on static fields.
while (input.hasNextDouble()) { /* <-- this wraps your nextDouble() call */
  setVariables(input.nextDouble(), tokenCounter++);
}

//several lines of code later 

public static void setVariables(double inputValue, tokenCounter){

  switch(tokenCounter){
   case 0: totalPointsAvailable = inputValue; break;
   case 1: homeworkWeight = inputValue; break;
   case 2: projectsWeight = inputValue; break;
   //Continue the switch/case based on the expected order of doubles
   //and make your variables static sense they seem changes to your code might
   //cause you to break up your main method and static variables will be easier 
   //to access across different methods.
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am going to rework the code and see if I can get it working.