# Calculating factorial for 0 leading to NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, factorial

I got to calculate the factorial of a number. As a fact factorial of 0 is 1. So I included that case in the function as well.
here's the code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Factorial {
    static int fact(int n) {
        int result;
        if (n == 0 || n == 1)
            return 1;

        result = fact(n - 1) * n;
        return result;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i, fact = 1;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        fact = fact(n);
        System.out.println(fact);
    }
}
```

but if I'm giving input as 0, some exception was raised

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
>     at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
>     at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
>     at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
>     at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
>     at Factorial.main(Factorial.java:14)

How to resolve this situation?

Edits:

1. I have changed the exception.All apologies for the thing that yes the code wasn't even 26 lines. I had put some code above as comments before posting just the code here.
2. This ain't a duplicate. As of the fact I want to know why it doesn't accept 0 as an input. It works perfect for all other inputs.
3. I use an online Compiler https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php
4. Works fine with Java Compiler of the PC JDK 1.7 ,but raises exception on online IDE.

Comment: It seems that the exception is not thrown by your method `fact()`, but from within `nextInt()` ... ? (And your posted code does not even have 25 lines)

Comment: Could you please share how you run your app?

Comment: I have checked your code and it runs fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729294/nosuchelementexception-with-java-util-scanner

Comment: Is it working on other inputs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoSuchElementException with Java.Util.Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729294/nosuchelementexception-with-java-util-scanner)

Answer (score 1):

`NoSuchElementException` will be thrown if no more tokens are available. This is caused by invoking nextInt() without checking if there's any integer available. To prevent it from happening, you may consider using hasNextInt() to check if any more tokens are available. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13729573/1664430).

Modified your code and added `hasNextInt` so that `NoSuchElementException` is not thrown and `sc.close()` to close the resource at the end of `main` method

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int fact = 1;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        fact = fact(n);
        System.out.println(fact);
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The online IDE is probably doing some kind of pre-processing of the data that
don't plays very nice with zeros.

TutorialPoint has online compilers for multiple languages and is very likely
that these all share some common backend that does the magic of passing text
from your browser to their servers. I'm not sure what kind of processing is
happening behind but I can imagine that is something like trimming the
unnecessary zeros from the left of the numbers or something like that.

I have encountered the opposite problem in standard C with the function sscanf,
which expected to fail (return 0) when the input string is empty just like its
sister function scanf but it still returns sucess and stores zero in the integer
variables.

By the way, if you just add a leading space or \n to the zero, everything works
just fine.