# showing nosuchelementexception in java

Tags: java

i am writing a code on stacks where i have used the scanner class but it is showing nosuchelementexception

This is the question:
As every other little boy, Mike has a favorite toy to play with. Mike's favorite toy is a set of N disks. The boy likes to compose his disks in stacks, but there's one very important rule: the disks in a single stack must be ordered by their radiuses in a strictly increasing order such that the top-most disk will have the smallest radius.

For example, a stack of disks with radii (5, 2, 1) is valid, while a stack of disks with radii (3, 4, 1) is not.

Little Mike has recently come up with the following algorithm after the order of disks are given:

First, Mike initiates an empty set of disk stacks.
Then, Mike processes the disks in the chosen order using the following pattern:
If there is at least one stack such that Mike can put the current disk on the top of the stack without making it invalid, then he chooses the stack with the smallest top disk radius strictly greater than the radius of the current disk, and puts the current disk on top of that stack.
Otherwise, Mike makes a new stack containing only the current disk.
For example, let's assume that the order of the disk radii is (3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 2). Here's how the set of the top stack disks will appear during the algorithm's run:

In the beginning of the algorithm, the set of disk stacks is empty. After processing the first disk, the set of top stack disks is {3}.
We cannot put the second disk on the only stack that we have after processing the first disk, so we make a new stack. After processing the second disk, the set of top stack disks is {3, 4}.
We cannot put the third disk on any of the available stacks, so we make a new stack. After processing the third disk, the set of top stack disks is {3, 4, 5}.
The fourth disk has radius 1, so it can be easily put on any of the available stacks. According to the algorithm, we choose the stack with the top disk radius equal to 3. After processing the fourth disk, the set of top stack disks is {1, 4, 5}.
The fifth disk has radius 1, so there are two stacks we can put it on. According to the algorithm, we choose the stack with the top disk radius equal to 4. After processing the fifth disk, the set of top stack disks is {1, 1, 5}.
The sixth disk has radius 2, so there is only one stack we can put it on. The final set of top stack disks is {1, 1, 2}.
here is the code..:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Codechef
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i,testcases,disks,currentdisk,j,stackarraytop=0,added;
        stack s;
        int[] num;
        stack[] sh= new stack[10];
        testcases=sc.nextInt();
        while(testcases-->0)
        {
            disks=sc.nextInt();
            num = new int[disks];
            for(i=0;i<disks;i++)
            {
                num[i]=sc.nextInt();
            }
            //System.out.print("no. of disks:"+disks+" input array of disks:"+num+"//\n");
            s = new stack(disks);
            for(j=0;j<disks;j++)
            {
                added=0;
                currentdisk=num[j];
                //System.out.println("current disk:"+currentdisk);
                if(j==0)
                {
                    s.add(currentdisk);
                    sh[stackarraytop++]=s;
                    //sh[0].displaystack();
                    //s.displaystack();
                    //System.out.println("stacks in the array:"+stackarraytop);
                    continue;
                }
                for(i=0;i<stackarraytop;i++)
                {
                   
                    //System.out.println("///"+i+" length:"+stackarraytop);
                    if(task.insertcheck(sh[i], currentdisk))
                        {
                            //System.out.println("stack top:"+sh[i].top);
                            sh[i].add(currentdisk);added=1;//sh[i].displaystack();/
                            break;
                        }
                }
                if(added==0)
                {
                    //System.out.println("creating new array:"+currentdisk);
                    stack b= new stack(disks-j);
                    b.initiate(disks-j);
                    b.add(currentdisk);
                    sh[stackarraytop++]=b;
                    //sh[stackarraytop-1].displaystack();
                }
                //System.out.println("stacks in the array:"+stackarraytop);
                //task.stackarraytops(sh,stackarraytop);
            }
            task.stackarraytops(sh,stackarraytop);
            stackarraytop=0;
            s.reset();
        }    
    }   //
}
class task{
    static Boolean insertcheck(stack stk,int n){
        int t= stk.top;
        if(n>=stk.stck[t-1])
        {
            //System.out.println("FALSE "+t+" // "+stk.stck[t-1]);
            return false;
        }
        else return true;
    }
    //static void arraystackentry(stack s,stack[] a,int sat){
      //  a[sat]=s;
    //}
    static void stackarraytops(stack[] s,int limit)
    {
        int i;
        //System.out.print("stackarrays:"+limit+" //");
        System.out.print(limit+" ");
        for(i=0;i<limit;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(s[i].stck[(s[i].top)-1]+" ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
class stack{
    public int[] stck;
    int elements=0;
    stack(int n){
        this.stck=new int[n];
    }
    int top = 0;
    void initiate(int n)
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            stck[i]=0;
        }
    }
    void add(int n)
    {
        stck[top++]=n;
        elements++;
    }
    int pop(int n)
    {
        top--;
        return stck[top];
    }
    void displaystack()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<elements;i++){
            System.out.print(stck[i]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    void reset()
    {
        top=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi if this solves your question let me/us know and we can close this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729294/nosuchelementexception-with-java-util-scanner

Comment: We didn't ask yet - what is your question, concretely?

Comment: https://www.codechef.com/problems/STACKS this is the problem. You have to enter custom data when you press "run" on codechef (just copy the sample data in the problem description) otherwise the program is run with no data and fails at the first sc.nextInt().